# PHP/javascript onchange not working with textarea

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am having a problem with this javascript function, but I am not sure what is really going on.
To keep the story short;
I made a dropdown list using select, with several options(project names). These options are taken from a database. Each project has a name(listed in the dropdown list) and content. The content is supposed to be loaded in to a textarea. Now this is the part that I made and works.

However, the problem is that when I change something in the content(in the textarea) of a project, the dropdown list stops working. I can still click on it and change to a different project, but that project is not loaded.

Here is my javascript

```
<script>
        function getContent()  {
            var mail = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var project = document.getElementById("projects").value;
            var xhr;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            var data = "project=" + project+  "&email=" + mail;
            xhr.open("POST", "/includes/projects.php", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.send(data);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = display_data;
            function display_data() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        //alert(xhr.responseText);
                        document.getElementById("projectcontent").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                    } else {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And here is my dropdown and textarea.

```
<form>
<select id="projects" onchange="getContent()"><option>Select project</option>
        <?php
        foreach($projects as $project)
        {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $project['id'];?>"><?php echo $project['name']; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
 </select><input type="hidden" id="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>" /></form><br />
<textarea id="projectcontent"></textarea>
```

What is going wrong here? Why does the getContent function work at the beginning, but when I change the content of the textarea, it stops working?

Comment: Are there any errors? Is the browser making an xhr request when you change the dropdown for the second time? In Chrome and Firefox you can press F12 to open the developer tools and check out the console for errors and xhr requests, clicking on them will show you the response as well. I prefer to use Firefox with Firebug plugin but that's just a personal reverence.

Comment: Yes, I do get the correct response, no errors. But it is solved already. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the value property of the text area not the innerHTML

```
document.getElementById("projectcontent").value = xhr.responseText;
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This was it. I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

you can make this function very simple using jquery.

```
function getContent()  
 {      
     var mail = $("#email").val();
     var project = $("#projects").val();

    $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/includes/projects.php",
            data : "project=" + project+  "&email=" + mail,
            success : function(result)  {  $("#projectcontent").val(result);  }
           });  
 }
```